# solving $1+\frac{1}{x} \gt 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In solving a larger problem, I ran into the following inequality which I must solve:

$$ 1+\frac{1}{x} \gt 0.$$

Looking at it for a while, I found that $x\gt 0$ and $x\lt -1$ are solutions. Please how do I formally show that these are indeed the solutions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two cases.  If $x>0$ we may multiply both sides by $x$ and the inequality is unchanged, i.e. $x+(1/x)x>0(x)$, which simplifies to $x+1>0$ or $x>-1$.  This case is the combination of $x>0$ and $x>-1$, which is $x>0$.

If $x<0$ we multiply both sides by $x$ and the inequality reverses, i.e. $x+(1/x)x<0(x)$, which simplifies to $x+1<0$ or $x<-1$.  This case is the combination of $x<0$ and $x<-1$, which is $x<-1$.

Comment: (+1) as this shows how $x$ must be considered positive and negative to obtain all solutions to the inequality.

Comment: Can I multiply both sides by $x^2$?

Comment: @Gorg, that's another way to go.  It has the advantage of always being positive, so there aren't two cases.  It has the disadvantage of leaving you with a slightly trickier polynomial inequality to solve.

Answer (score 11):

You asked how to show this formally, so a picture is possibly not very useful, but I include one because I need practice with tikz. Vadim's answer above is excellent.

[image]

Comment: I'm jealous - trying to get good with tikz myself. Great graph!

Comment: I'm jealous, too. Can you post the code for creating the graph?

Comment: Thanks! It really does just take time and practice and some help from tex.stackexchange.

Comment: \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\draw[blue, thick, domain=-5:-1, samples = 250] plot (\x,{1/\x + 1});
\draw[red, thick, domain=-1:-0.3, samples = 250] plot (\x,{1/\x + 1});
\draw[blue, thick, domain=0.3:5, samples = 250] plot (\x,{1/\x + 1}) node [right] {$f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$};

\draw[black, thick, ->] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[black, thick, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};

\draw[black, thick, dashed] (-1,-3) -- (-1,0) node [below=0.25cm, left] {$-1$} -- (-1,5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Comment: If I could upvote more, I would.

Why do you suggest that a picture is not formal proof though?

Comment: @joneshf It needs a little bit of work to show that this really is the right way to draw $1 + 1/x$, and that it doesn't dip under the axis again at a later stage.

Comment: Interesting, I thought it'd be fairly straight forward that it's the same as the graph of $1/x$ just shifted.  So you could infer the same shifted asymptotes and general behavior.

Comment: Yes, but how do we know what $1/x$ looks like? We should really take is derivative, show that it's decreasing everywhere, evaluate the limit at infinities and zero, look for intercepts and all that.

Answer (score 5):

After reading your comment here is how to go about it when you multiply by $x^2$. So we need to solve

$$x^2 + x > 0.$$

That can be written as

$$x(x + 1) > 0.$$

Now the product of two numbers is positive when both numbers are positive or when both are negative. Therefore we have two cases to solve:

**Case 1**:

$x >0$ and $x + 1> 0$

Both of these inequalities are satisfied when $x > 0$.

**Case 2**:

$x < 0$ and $x + 1 < 0$

Both of these inequalities are satisfied when $x < -1$.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

note that $\frac{x+1}{x}>0$ and $(x+1)x>0$ have the same solution(or, as you mentioned, multiply them both with $x^2$)

generally speaking, bringing the denominator over the bar doesn't change the answer, but be careful that the denominator can't be zero.